# Pycharm: library initialization failed

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm Community IDE got an error: `library initialization failed - unable to allocate file descriptor table - out of memory Aborted`.

While running that appliation from commandline, that is: `#./pycharm.sh`

Comment: worked fine for Pycharm version 2018.3 on MacOSx

Comment: @dkb I'm using ver. 2017.3.3

Comment: Please update with 2018.3 and try, should not be a problem.

Comment: I have the same problem using PyCharm version 2018.3.2. The problem arose using the `pycharm.sh` script, the [snap option](https://snapcraft.io/pycharm-community) and the [flatpak option](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.jetbrains.PyCharm-Community) too using Linux.

Comment: @guzman you may try using the command from terminal `java -Xms256m -Xmx2048m` , referring to some other answer: [memory allocation java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763095/9526947). I've tried ... but, not worked. And have other various issues with the system, so re-installed the system. ️